# Create new list from namedtuple attribute

Tags: python, list, namedtuple

I'm trying to copy book names that are <2000 into a new list. But the problem I'm having is that it only copies "1984" and it's copying it as an individual character to the list rather than copying all the names that it's supposed to

```
from collections import namedtuple
Book = namedtuple('Book','author title genre year price instock')

BSI = [ Book('John Green', 'Paper Towns', 'Young Adult', 2008, 7.00, 200),
        Book('Beverly Clearly', 'Ramona Forever', 'Children', 1924, 9.00, 150),
        Book('Vladmir Nabokov', 'Lolita', 'Tragicomedy', 1958, 15.00 , 80),
        Book('J.D. Salinger', 'Catcher in the Rye', 'Young Adult', 1951, 10.00, 130),
        Book('George Orwell', '1984', 'Dystopia', 1949, 7.00, 300),
        Book('Jeannette Walls','The Glass Castle','Memoir', 2006, 15.00 , 100)]

older_books = []

for books in BSI:
    if (books.year<2000):
        older_books=list(books.title)

print(older_books) #Outputs ['1', '9', '8', '4']
```

What it should output

> Ramona Forever
>   Lolita
>   Catcher in the Rye
>   1984

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With each `for` loop, the code is overwriting the list `older_books` with the last book title (converted to list) since you're not appending to it but merely creating a new list each time.

```
>>> list('Ramona Forever')
['R', 'a', 'm', 'o', 'n', 'a', ' ', 'F', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'r']
>>> list('1984')
['1', '9', '8', '4']
```

Use [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) so that all book titles that match the condition will be appended to a single list:

```
>>> older_books = []
>>> older_books.append('Ramona Forever')
>>> older_books.append('1984')
>>> older_books
['Ramona Forever', '1984']
```

---

```
for books in BSI:
    if books.year < 2000:
        older_books.append(books.title)  # <---
```

**UPDATE** Alternative using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
older_books = [b.title for b in BSI if b.year < 2000]
```

Comment: Alternatively, this problem is well-handled by a list comprehension: `older_books = [b.title for b in BSI if b.year < 2000]`

Comment: @mtrw, Thank you for the comment. I added that alternative solution to the answer accordingly.